# How to set up Windows on VM using Powershell (Hyper-V)

Tags: powershell, operating-systems, hyper-v, configure

I know how to create a VM and I know how to start that VM on Hyper-V using the script of Powershell but it's the first use of the VM so I need to set up Windows and I don't know how using the Powershell.

Comment: Can you please explain what parts to configure using PowerShell, did you try googling your question?

Comment: @doenoe Yes I did and I didn't find the answer. I'm new at this. First, I can create a VM and I can start it but then I have to configure the OS because it's the first use of the VM. I don't know how to configure it using the script. Do you have some idea?

Comment: What do you mean by configure the OS? Is the OS already installed on the vm, or is that the part thats missing? If you create a VM, its VHD (virtual hard disk) does not contain an OS. You will need to manually add an ISO file to the IDE controller of the VM. Next step will be booting up, and voila. You will be prompted to configure your fresh install of the given ISO.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj933287.aspx

Comment: @doenoe I mean, how to set up Windows using the script.

Comment: To properly automate Windows installs you'd use Answer files and sysprep, not PowerShell.  After Windows is installed on a working VM, it's just another machine, you can configure it with PowerShell (or whatever) just like you would any other machine.  As-is this is too broad, and makes little sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to setup a VM with the use of PowerShell.

```
 # Variables
$CLI1 = "50331-CUSTOM-CLI"      # Name of VM running Client Operating System
$SRV1 = "50331-CUSTOM-SRV"      # Name of VM running Server Operating System
$CRAM = 2GB                             # RAM assigned to Client Operating System
$SRAM = 1GB                             # RAM assigned to Server Operating System
$CLI1VHD = 80GB                             # Size of Hard-Drive for Client Operating System
$SRV1VHD = 40GB                             # Size of Hard-Drive for Server Operating System
$VMLOC = "C:\HyperV"                    # Location of the VM and VHDX files
$NetworkSwitch1 = "PrivateSwitch1"  # Name of the Network Switch
$W7ISO = "C:\Labfiles\Windows7.iso" # Windows 7 ISO
$W7VFD = "C:\Labfiles\Windows7.vfd" # Windows 7 Virtual Floppy Disk with autounattend.xml file
$WSISO = "C:\Labfiles\W2K8R2.iso"           # Windows Server 2008 ISO
$WSVFD = "C:\Labfiles\W2K8R2.vfd"   # Windows Server 2008 Virtual Floppy Disk with autounattend.xml file

# Create VM Folder and Network Switch
MD $VMLOC -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$TestSwitch = Get-VMSwitch -Name $NetworkSwitch1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue; if ($TestSwitch.Count -EQ 0){New-VMSwitch -Name $NetworkSwitch1 -SwitchType Private}

# Create Virtual Machines
New-VM -Name $CLI1 -Path $VMLOC -MemoryStartupBytes $CRAM -NewVHDPath $VMLOC\$CLI1.vhdx -NewVHDSizeBytes $CLI1VHD -SwitchName $NetworkSwitch1
New-VM -Name $SRV1 -Path $VMLOC -MemoryStartupBytes $SRAM -NewVHDPath $VMLOC\$SRV1.vhdx -NewVHDSizeBytes $SRV1VHD -SwitchName $NetworkSwitch1

# Configure Virtual Machines
Set-VMDvdDrive -VMName $CLI1 -Path $W7ISO
Set-VMDvdDrive -VMName $SRV1 -Path $WSISO
Set-VMFloppyDiskDrive -VMName $CLI1 -Path $W7VFD
Set-VMFloppyDiskDrive -VMName $SRV1 -Path $WSVFD
Start-VM $SRV1
Start-VM $CLI1
```

Comment: Please dont forget to mark as answer if you are satisfied with the given answer. :)

Comment: if you're just going to copy/paste your answer you should at least cite your source.

Comment: If you're just going to comment a link, might as well give the answer right away